# EmberJS: Escape entire template

Tags: ember.js, add-on

All,
  I'm writing an EmberJS addon that produces an application that can be used with JSP.

The problem I'm running into is that I need to escape large chunks of code so ember cli doesn't error out on me.

Is there a way to force ember to ignore error checking on a specific file?

tyia

Comment: please be more specific, what error do you mean? JSHint?

Comment: Please provide an sample error output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the JSHint errors, the way to mute them for certain file(s) is to add a `.jshintignore` file into your project.

A sample `.jshintignore` file can be found at below,

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintignore